# GEE: how to make an average of values from the same day

Tags: google-earth-engine

I filter out the clouds, shadows and snow from the Landsat 8 data and calculate the NDVI. Examining the values in more detail, I found that some are for the same day twice. I suspect the problem is caused by overlapping images, with the point being between/on both. I tried to find a solution, but I couldn't find anything.

What I need: a function to create an average of the duplicated values in same days.

My code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/dd0afc7fa1829310e3195ffaea2bc2b7

```
// bufferu function
function bufferPoints(radius, bounds) {
  return function(pt) {
    pt = ee.Feature(pt);
    return bounds ? pt.buffer(radius).bounds() : pt.buffer(radius);
  };
}
// cloud, shadow and snow filter: fmask (qa)
function fmask(image) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  var snowBitMask = (1 << 4); // snow
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0))
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(snowBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}
// calculation of indices
function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']).rename('NDVI')
  return image.addBands([ndvi])
}
function addNDMI(image) {
  var ndmi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B6']).rename('NDMI')
  return image.addBands([ndmi])
}
function addNDSI(image) {
  var ndsi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B6']).rename('NDSI')
  return image.addBands([ndsi])
}
function addEVI(image) {
  var evi = image.expression(
    '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
      'NIR': image.select('SR_B5'),
      'RED': image.select('SR_B4'),
      'BLUE': image.select('SR_B2')}).rename('EVI');
  return image.addBands([evi])
}
// _____________________________

// DATA

var ptsEast = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(
        [[117.94363514659328, 46.70941786484102],
         [119.42678944346828, 46.807262069830664],
         [119.41580311534328, 47.03986601821814],
         [119.07522694346828, 47.09224973615361],
         [118.85550038096828, 47.159524596123624],
         [118.71267811534328, 47.159524596123624],
         [118.52591053721828, 47.159524596123624],
         [118.37210194346828, 47.1371090963271],
         [118.11941639659328, 47.159524596123624]]));

var ptsGobi = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Geometry.Point([96.9963300116736, 43.375274461112205]));
    
// merge points together
var ptsMerge = ptsEast.merge(ptsGobi)
var ptsBuff = ptsMerge.map(bufferPoints(30, true));

// Landsat 8 + filtering
var startDate = '2019-01-01'
var endDate = '2020-01-01'

var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,9, 'month'))
              .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
              .filterBounds(ptsBuff)
              .map(fmask)
              .map(addNDVI)
              .map(addNDMI)
              .map(addNDSI)
              .map(addEVI);
              
// Chart maker
print(ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: L8.select('NDVI'),
  regions: ptsBuff,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30
}).setOptions({title: 'NDVI - Landsat 8'}));

// ___
Map.addLayer(ptsMerge.draw({color: 'red', strokeWidth: 5}), {}, 'drawn');
Map.centerObject(ptsMerge);
```

for example area 1: 24 Aug 2019
[image]

Comment: Your question needs more details. What were you doing? What solution did you try? It would be better if you share your code.

Comment: I edited the post. sorry, I had a busy day yesterday, now all the information is listed, I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to map over a list of distinct days, mosaicing all the images for that day:

```
var withDates = L8.map(function(img) { 
  return img.set('date', img.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
})

var mosaicList = withDates.aggregate_array('date')
  .distinct()
  .map(function(date) {
    var d = ee.Date(date)
    return L8.filterDate(d, d.advance(1, 'day')).mosaic().set('system:index', date)
  })
  
var mosaics = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(mosaicList)
print(mosaics)
```